# How to copy file name of currently opened file in sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

How do you copy the file name of the currently opened file in sublime text 3 ?
If this is not possible by default, perhaps you know some sublime extension which does that job using keyboard shortcut.

Comment: You can right-click within the file and select "Copy File Path", would that do?

Comment: @MattDMo Please add that as an answer. I did not see your comment. This is the only answer that works currenly.

Comment: @SohailSi all set

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do this if you have the [SideBarEnhancements](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements) plugin installed.

1. Open up the command palette with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (on Mac it is <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)
2. Type `File: Copy Name` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

The file name has now been copied to your clipboard.

---

**Setting a hotkey for this command**:

1. Go to your *Key Bindings -> User* file
2. Add this line to your file: `{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+l"], "command": "side_bar_copy_name" }`
3. Change `"ctrl+shift+l"` to whatever command you want to use.

Comment: This function is now called `File: Copy Absolute Path`.

Comment: This just copied the name of the file. What if I want to copy the full PATH?

Comment: It didn't work for me. No `file: Copy`.   (even using `absolute`). Youo probably have a plugin that enables that. (as of 9 July 2021, build 4107)

Comment: Yeah, the first line of this answer mentions you can do it if you have the SideBarEnhancements plugin installed

Answer (score 1):

In Sublime Text 3 and 4, you can simply right-click within the file body itself and select `Copy File Path`.

Using the [`SideBarEnhancements`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SideBarEnhancements) plugin is also an option when you're browsing through files contained within folders that you have added to your project (that show on the lower part of the sidebar). There, just right-click on the file and select `Copy Path` or `Copy Dir Path`.

Answer (score 0):

You can download [CopyFileName](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Copy%20File%20Name) to do just that.

To install it, extract the [.zip file](https://github.com/nwjlyons/copy-file-name/archive/master.zip) to your Packages folder, wich you can access via:

`Preferences --> Browse packages`

To actually use it:

`Open or preview the file --> Right click somewhere in it (not on the tab) --> Copy File Name`

Comment: This functionality is currently built in to ST, you don't need a plugin.